# Create size indicators inside scene in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a small 3D wardrobe studio and I'd like to add size indicators into it, so theoretically, I'd loop all the children I want the indicators between and display the number along with an arrow.

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how would I render the arrows and the numbers. Also, I was looking for an already existing solution, but couldn't find any.

My question is, how would I render the arrows between child elements? Are those vectors? It seems like a lot of work to do, do you know any existing solutions? Thank you in advance.

*Size indicators don't need to look exactly like those in the picture, it's just for the problem visualization*

Comment: Take a look at `ArrowHelper` and `Font` in [the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/) to see if they might provide the tools you're seeking.

Comment: @TheJim01 I'm not sure if I'd be able to write that from scratch by myself. But I'll try to and let you know of the results. Anyways, if you have some free time, I would really appreciate the code sample as an answer to that question.

Comment: [Here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/units-in-three-js/1174/24?u=prisoner849) I extended a box helper. Sorry, no code, gif only, as it's a private project ^^ Arrows are custom buffer geometries, not arrow helpers. Numbers are textures.